# How can I output every line an XUnit test touches upon execution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xunit

I have an application that I can step through debugging when executing an Xunit test case. I want to log every line it touches so I can read the whole flow in one long page (like a log file of source code).

How can I output the execution to a log file?

For the curious, this is so I can see the flow of some legacy code to figure out the logic required for a rewrite. Of course, the requirements, use cases, etc was not maintained so this is my strategy to pull it from the only source of truth: current production code.

```
method1(var a)
{
    print(" test " + a);
    method2(a * 2);
}

method2(var b)
{
    if (b > 10)
    {
        print("b too big");
    }
    else
    {
        print("b is " + b);
    }
}
```

Test case executes `method1(2);` so output would be something like:

```
class1.method1(2).print(" test " + a);
class1.method1(2).method2(a * 2);
class1.method2(4).if (b > 10)
class1.method2(4).else
class1.method2(4).print("b is " + b);
```

Is this possible to get this log? If so, does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not an easy task, you would need to attach a custom debugger through code to your running process or start a new process with a your debugger attached.

Step through each line (so that it breaks after each statement, read your your current stack location, and output the line where it's currently at. Potentially needing to map and use the .pdb file and source code.

Generally, a very hard task to do!

Comment: I was afraid of that!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to log all executed methods with parameters. I haven't tried it with an XUnit test, but it is probably possible to configure customized run settings for monitoring.

Comment: We used ANTS which does this as well. Thinking of maybe doing a GUI macro to copy paste the code and variables at that line and append to a file.